# cpp, "\0" == NULL returns false? How to figure it is null ptr or not?

Tags: c++, string-literals, null-pointer

I am getting these results. What am I doing wrong?

```
const char *c = "\0";
cout << (c == NULL); // false
cout << (c == nullptr); //false
```

Comment: I think you're confusing what a *pointer is* versus *what it points to*. This is an extremely important distinction that must be understood before using pointers in any capacity. Here `c` points to an empty C string, but it is absolutely not a "null pointer" in any way. It **is** assigned. Imagine in other languages like Java this is `null` vs `""`.

Comment: `"\0"` isn't what you believe it is.

Comment: `"\0"` is a string literal.  Why do you expect it to be null?  Are you maybe confusing it with a null-terminator?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I am actually confused of the concept of null-terminator. I thought the null-terminator actually enforce the "c" to point to nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All literal strings in C++ are really constant arrays of characters, *including* the null-terminator character.

So doing e.g.

```
const char* c = "\0";
```

is somewhat equivalent to

```
char const internal_string_array[] = { '\0', '\0' };
const char* c = &internal_string_array[0];
```

So a pointer to a literal string will *never* be a null pointer.

Also there's a difference between a null *pointer* and the string null terminator character. A null pointer is a pointer which have been initialized to point to nowhere. A string null terminator character is the character `'\0'`. These two are different things.

---

If you want to check to see if a C-style string (using pointers *or* arrays) is empty, then you first need to make sure it's not a null-pointer (if you're using pointers) and then check to see if the first character is the string null terminator character:

```
if (c == nullptr)
{
    // No string at all!
}
else if (c[0] == '\0')
{
    // String exists, but is empty
}
else
{
    // String exists, and is not empty
}
```

For `std::string` objects (which you should use for almost all your strings) then you don't need the null-pointer check:

```
if (str.empty())
{
    // String is empty
}
else
{
    // String is not empty
}
```

Also note that even if a string is not empty, it might contain unprintable characters (like the ASCII control characters), or characters that are "invisible" (like for example space or tab). So if printing the non-empty string it might not show anything.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `std::string` may even contain null chars and be considered to be non-empty: `std::string str("\0"sv); assert(!str.empty()); assert(str.at(0) == '\0');` won't trigger an assertion error in debug mode. Your code for C-style strings has a different behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer `c` is not a null pointer because it points to the string literal `"\0"`.

```
const char *c = "\0";
```

To declare a null pointer you could write for example

```
const char *c = nullptr;
```

or

```
const char *c = 0;
```

If you want to check whether the pointer points to a null string (provided that it indeed points to a string) then write

```
cout <<  !*c;
```

Comment: A null pointer doesn't point to a null (= empty?) string, but you can't do `!*c` on it.

Comment: @Evg Your comment does not make sense. Reread my answer one more. Nevertheless I have updated the answer.

Comment: If it hadn't made sense, you needn't have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the string's length, then in C++ you'd use `std::string` which can tell you straight up if it is [`empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty), or in C you'd check with `strlen(c) == 0`.

An empty string is actual data, even if it's not necessarily a whole lot of data. It is completely different from a "null" pointer which is one that does not point at *any* data at all.

The `\0` part of the `"\0"` string is called "NUL" or "NUL byte" to avoid confusion with "NULL" as in pointer, and is how it's described in the [ASCII standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).